# SQL Join with Group By

Tags: sql, join, group-by

Ok, so i'm trying to write a complex query (at least complex to me) and need some pro help.  This is my database setup:

Table: MakeList

```
| MakeListId | Make     |
| 1          | Acura    |
| 2          | Chevy    |
| 3          | Pontiac  |
| 4          | Scion    |
| 5          | Toyota   |
```

Table: CustomerMake

```
| CustomerMakeId | CustomerId | _Descriptor |
| 1              | 123        | Acura       |
| 2              | 124        | Chevy       |
| 3              | 125        | Pontiac     |
| 4              | 126        | Scion       |
| 5              | 127        | Toyota      |
| 6              | 128        | Acura       |
| 7              | 129        | Chevy       |
| 8              | 130        | Pontiac     |
| 9              | 131        | Scion       |
| 10             | 132        | Toyota      |
```

Table: Customer

```
| CustomerId | StatusId |
| 123        | 1        |
| 124        | 1        |
| 125        | 1        |
| 126        | 2        |
| 127        | 1        |
| 128        | 1        |
| 129        | 2        |
| 130        | 1        |
| 131        | 1        |
| 132        | 1        |
```

What i am trying to end up with is this...

Desired Result Set:

```
| Make    | CustomerId|
| Acura   | 123       |
| Chevy   | 124       |
| Pontiac | 125       |
| Scion   | 131       |
| Toyota  | 127       |
```

I am wanting a list of unique Makes with one **active (StatusId = 1)** CustomerId to go with it.  I'm assuming i'll have to do some `GROUP BYs` and `JOINS` but i haven't been able to figure it out.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Let me know if i haven't given enough info for my question.  Thanks!

UPDATE: The script doesn't have to be performant - it will be used one time for testing purposes.

Comment: Why not CustomerID=128 for the Acura? How do you decide which one to take if there is more than one?

Comment: It can be either one, but i only need one.  As long as the customer is active (StatusId = 1) it can be either customer.  I was just taking the first available active customer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
select cm._Descriptor,
       min(cu.customerid)
from CustomerMake cm
  join Customer cu on cuo.CustomerId  = cm.CustomerId and cu.StatusId = 1
group by cm._Descriptor
```

I left out the MakeList table as it seems unnecessary because you are storing the full make name as `_Descriptor`in the CustomerMake table anyway (so the question is what is the MakeList table for? Why don't you store a FK to it in the CustomerMake table?)

Comment: I just get a `Column 'CustomerMake._Descriptor' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.` error with that.  And to answer you're question - there's more in that table, just not needed for what i'm trying to do.

Comment: @ryanpitts1: sorry, forgot the group by.

Comment: Awesome, that got what i needed.  Thanks.  Think i was over complicating it a bit.

Answer (score 1):

You want to

(a) join the customer and customermake tables
(b) filter on customer.statusid
(c) group by customermake._descriptor

Depending on your RDBMS, you may need to explicitly apply a group function to customer.customerid to include it in the select list.  Since you don't care which particular customerid is displayed, you could use MIN or MAX to just pick an essentially arbitrary value.

Comment: Any chance you could script that out?  I had an idea of _what_ i needed to do, just not how to script it out.

Comment: I was hoping to give you some help learning to fish, instead of just throwing you some fish.  But @a_horse_with_no_name has written it for you.

Comment: Yea, i appreciate that...usually i would like that but i'm in a bit of a time crunch as the task is kind of a one time deal.